# Как подключить из другого сайта инклюдом файл?

Tags: php

Выдает ошибку:

> Warning: include(): http:// wrapper is
> disabled in the server configuration
> by allow_url_include=0 in
> /home/bridun/html/hoto.tk/index.php on
> line 58

Может, что-то в хтачес писать?

Comment: так явно же пишет - allow_url_include у Вас 0 в php.ini. Нужно исправить на 1 (скорее всего).

Comment: прописал в хтачес,  вылезла ошибка 500 Server error.

Comment: Зачем? Тебе тогда 500 ошибки сыпаться не будут. И ты не сможешь отладить написанный код. Не делай так никогда.

Answer (score 1):

В ошибке четко написано: "Включение файлов по url выключено в настройках php, а именно в директиве `allow_url_include`, значение которой = 0."

Откройте php.ini и измените значение на единицу.

**UPD**

Файл php.ini может находится где угодно. Если у вас Ubuntu, то, скорее всего, он тут:

- корневой в /etc пользовательский-cgi
- в /var/www/пользователь/data/php-bin

Открой файл php.ini и найди в ней строку:

```
allow_url_include = 0
```

Замени ноль на единицу и сохрани файл.

Для того, чтобы изменения вступили в силу нужно перезагрузить сервер. У вас это, скорее всего, apache.

Comment: это в хтачес прописать

Comment: смотри UPD

Comment: файла не существует, php.ini есть только хтачес

Comment: А на чем у Вас сайт написан?